# cannot resolve symbol page

Tags: java, android

Guys I have code to display an image/drawable  . I keep getting the error "cannot resolve symbol page " I am sure I am complicating issues are little here there must be an easier way to do this. I am using the example from http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

```
package com.geka.deviceinsight.home;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.Globals;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.R;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by timothycoutlakis on 2015/02/14.
 */
public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
{
   // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
   private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
      ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
      expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
      expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
      expandableList.setClickable(true);
      // Set the Items of Parent
      setGroupParents();
      // Set The Child Data
      setChildData();
      // Create the Adapter
      myExpandableAdaptorActivity adapter = new myExpandableAdaptorActivity(parentItems, childItems);
      adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
      // Set the Adapter to expandableList
      expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
      expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
   }
   // method to add parent Items
   public void setGroupParents()
   {
      parentItems.add("Above Grade");
      parentItems.add("Acre");
      parentItems.add("A/C Circuit");
      parentItems.add("Accelerator");
      parentItems.add("Adhesion");
      parentItems.add("Adhesive Failure");
   }
   // method to set child data of each parent
   public void setChildData()
   {
      // Add Child Items for Above Grade
      ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");
       child.add(0,String.valueOf(R.drawable.buildexpo));

       context = getApplicationContext(); Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, page.getImageId());
       getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(2130837568);
      childItems.add(child);

      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");

      childItems.add(child);

      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");

      childItems.add(child);

      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");

      childItems.add(child);

      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");

      childItems.add(child);

      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("In plaster walls, strips of metal mesh bent at right angles and embedded in corners of ceilings and walls to prevent the plaster from cracking.");

      childItems.add(child);

   }
}
```

Comment: Declare rightly ?? `page.getImageId()`

Answer (score 0):

That means you either don't have a variable called `page`, or it's in a scope unreachable to where you try to use it.

Comment: is there are more comprehensive way to retrieve the image ? in that line by omiiting page and or that getImageID method

Comment: We have no idea what you are trying to do, we have no idea about the rest of your code, so we can't know this.

Comment: I actually want to know how to retrieve and image an display it I feel I might have added too much complexity so a better suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what you are working with: Swing? JavaFX? JSP? JSF? GWT? ...
And that's just a start of what we don't know.

Comment: I am using android studio(java) and what I posted is my java code . I am using an example from this link. http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html  The only difference is I am trying display an image below the description

Comment: No, what you posted is a very very very small snippet of your Java code. on it's own, it can't work, where 's the rest of the code?

Comment: so, where do you declare your page variable? It's not in this class. Is it in a/the super class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101848/discussion-between-zidane-and-stultuske).

Comment: there is no discussion. Your problem is, you are using variables that don't exist, thát is your problem.

Comment: well I want to know if I even have to use or declare page and use getImage to retrieve an image
there could be a simpler way?